# IBM MQ : Any way to get connection interruption notification?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ-7.5. I am running a jms client which connects to the manager running on some other hosts.

I want to monitor the TCP connections with the manager. How do I get notified if my client connection is broken with the manager ? Is there any callback or listener provided in IBM MQ APIs to know any interruption on connection ?

Eg. Like ActiveMQ has http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportListener.html

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to monitor client application connections at the queue manager end or in the client application?

To get notified of any connection issues, MQ JMS client has an `ExceptionListener` that can be attached to `MQConnection`. This exception listener will be invoked when there is an issue with connection to queue manager, for example connection to queue manager is broken. More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQConnection.html): View details of `setExceptionListener` method. Call the `setExceptionListener` method on MQConnection to register a callback as shown below.

```
  MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
  ExceptionListener exceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(){
                @Override
                public void onException(JMSException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    if(e.getLinkedException() != null)
                        System.out.println(e.getLinkedException());
                }
            };
 MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
 connection.setExceptionListener(exceptionListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, It was helpful. Is there also a way to check if my connection with MQ is healthy and up ? Eg. something like connection.isConnected() ?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of connections being dropped a connection broken exception will be sent via the exception listener.

The JMS Specification is written such that events such as connection broken are legitimately returned on synchronous calls only.  I would also recommended setting an exception listener, and to catch exceptions from all messaging operations and taking appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

To actively check the health of connection and session, i am thinking of using below approach.

```
/**
 * Method to check if connection is healthy or not.
 * It creates a session and close it. mqQueueConnection
 * is the connection for which we want to check the health. 
 */
protected boolean isConnectionHealthy()
{
    try {
        Session session = mqQueueConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        session.close();
    }
    catch(JMSException e) {
        LOG.warn("Exception occured while checking health of connection. Not able to create " + "new session" + e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Method to check if session is healthy or not.
 * It creates a consumer and close it. mqQueueSession
 * is the session for which we want to check the health.
 */
protected boolean isSessionHealthy()
{
    try {
        MessageConsumer consumer = mqQueueSession.createConsumer(mqQueue);
        consumer.close();
    }
    catch(JMSException e) {
        LOG.warn("Exception occured while checking health of the session. Not able to create "
            + "new consumer" + e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Does it approach looks good ?

I just have one fear here: 
I am creating a test session in isConnectionhealthy() method and closing it. Will it not affect the already created session which is actually used for real communication? I mean will it do something like it closed already created session and started new one ?

Comment: The above type check does not guarantee connection being available when application makes any calls, like Producer.send or Consumer.receive. Because connection could break when application is makes send/receive call. Instead I would choose to make the API call itself and handle any exceptions thrown. If it's a connection broken exception, then do re-connect or use automatic reconnection option provided by MQ JMS client itself.

Comment: make sense. But my client application is an asynchronous listener which uses onMessage() method to receive message. mqConsumer.setMessageListener(obj); How do I check here ?

Comment: Also let say if my connection goes down while doing producer.send or consumer.receive. I will still be able to check that because above code will be running periodically and isConnectionHealthy() function will return false when the code tries to create session on this. Similar with isSessionHealthy().

Comment: If connection is broken, your MessageListener.onMessage will not get called, instead ExceptionListener.onException will get called. You could then take appropriate action, like reconnect. If connection goes down while calling send/receive, the call will return with an exception (MQRC 2009 in case of MQ). You can simply catch that exception and take action. In such case, I don't see the need for isSessionHealthy!